# Vagrant not syncing files to Virtual Machine

Tags: laravel, vagrant, windows-10, virtualbox

I am using Vagrant with Homestead on Windows 10 to sync my Laravel app to virtualbox.

Everything seems fine until i run laravel app in browser via custom domain like *laravel.app* then i get error `No input file specified`.

When i ssh into virtualbox i see that no files have been added from my project folder.
My **homestead.yaml** is most definitely configured correctly and i have entry in hosts file for custom domain.

I use all the latest versions and i did `vagrant provision`
I think my problem is somewhere in virtualbox but don't know where.

Here is my homestead.yaml config file http://pastebin.com/nJCqD4Qq

Comment: What about changing `C:/wamp64/www` to `C:\wamp64\www`.

Comment: Nope, it should be forward slashes. I logically first added it with back slashes but it didn't work and people commented i need to use forward.

Comment: Ok, I mine is folders:
    - map: C:\Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects and thought it might be worth a comment.

Comment: Long time ago but probably it helps someone: have you tried using escaped backslashes like `C:\\wamp64\\www`?